# Stripe (Customer Portal) downgrading plan at the end of biling cycle

Tags: python, stripe-payments

Stripe gives possiblity to update subscription plan in Customer Portal. This feature has 3 variants:

- switch plans without proration
- switch plan with proration and invoice immediately
- switch plan with proration and invoice on the end of billing period

In my app every plan has got assigned credits. By default proration is time-based, so I can't turn it on (someone can use all credits at day 1 and upgrade/downgrade next day and get full refund). The problem is that switching plans without proration causing immediate update without charging customer.

How can I upgrade/downgrade plan with API but I don't want to copy all features to only overwrite this one.  at the end of billing cycle with Customer Portal? It's pretty easy with API but I don't want to copy all features to only overwrite this one.

Answer (score 1):

The Customer Portal does not support limiting the downgrade to occur only at the end of the billing cycle. With cancellation, you can set the [cancellation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customer_portal/configurations/create#create_portal_configuration-features-subscription_cancel-mode) to occur at the end of period. However, with an update there is not and as you said, it will either [prorate, send an invoice or not prorate](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customer_portal/configurations/create#create_portal_configuration-features-subscription_update-proration_behavior) depending on what you choose. In your case, it might be worth taking a look at the `always_invoice` [option](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/upgrade-downgrade#immediate-payment). It calculates the proration, then immediately generates an invoice after making the switch.

Comment: `always_invoice` is equivalent to `prorate immediately` so it's not solving problem in this case

Answer (score 0):

> someone can use all credits at day 1 and upgrade/downgrade next day and get full refund

That's not how Stripe handles downgrades - no refund triggers for them.
What would happen is your Customer would get a credit applied to their `balance`, which would then reduce the price of future Invoices.

You could listen for `customer.updated` events to check for changes to the `balance`, and intervene (i.e. clear the `balance`) in case some customer is trying to exploit downgrades, however I'm not sure how easy that would be to implement in your app.

Ultimately, if you *are* trying to set different `proration_behavior` values between upgrades and downgrades (it's not really clear from your question), this isn't possible with the Billing Portal.
The best solution (though it's arguably not great), would be to handle the upgrade / downgrade on your side, then redirect the customer to the confirmation page of the portal using `flow_data`:
https://stripe.com/docs/customer-management/portal-deep-links